# Open specific path using Storage access framework

Tags: java, android, android-intent, storage-access-framework

I am able to write the text files by opening the **Files app** using the intent. But when I open the Files app through intent it is opening Downloads path instead I would like to open a **specific path**. Is that possible ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName);
startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I would like to launch the Files app using Intent and it should open specific path. I have tried *intent.setDataAndType* by passing the Uri, but it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in order to indicate the initial location of documents navigator you should add this to your intent :

```
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, your_initial_uri);
```

like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, your_initial_uri);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName);
startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: I have tried the same code, it is still not the opening the folder I wanted.

Comment: requires API level 26

Comment: @Perseus how did you compose your uri? Did you get it from a file path?

Comment: @ShinChven were u able to find a solution?

Comment: @ElioKhattar Did you find any solution?

Comment: @ShinChven, no. Some thread advised that you can open the document file selector pointing to a default file path, only in case the provided path is related to a "DocumentFile" object you created urself.